# Proof that $\det(A)=\det(A^T)$ using permutations.

Tags: linear-algebra, permutations, determinant, transpose

I'm reading a proof for the identity $\det(A) = \det(A^T)$ and I'm trying to udnerstand why the following rows are equivalent:

$$\eqalign{
  & \det ({A}) = \sum\limits_{\pi  \in {S_n}} {{\mathop{\rm sgn}} (\pi ) \cdot {a_{\pi (1),1}}} ...{a_{\pi (n),n}}  \cr 
  & \det ({A^T}) = \sum\limits_{\pi  \in {S_n}} {{\mathop{\rm sgn}} ({\pi ^{ - 1}}) \cdot {a_{1,{\pi ^{ - 1}}(1)}}} ...{a_{n,{\pi ^{ - 1}}(n)}} \cr} $$

Intuitively, I can understand that each term appears in both of the summations.
How to understand it algebraically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$f : \sigma \in S_n \rightarrow f(\sigma) =\sigma^{-1} \in S_n$ is a bijection (you can trivially check it is its own inverse), and this is a general fact that for a finite sum $\sum_{i \in A}u_i = \sum_{j \in B}u_{f(j)}$ if $f$ is a bijection from $B$ to $A$ (actually it also works for some infinite sums, such as sums with only positive terms).

As you said, it just states that in both sums each term appears exactly once and since addition is commutative, order doesn't matter.

Comment: Actually I didn't read carefully your question. My answer only explains why the second row is equal to $det(A)$ where $\pi$ (and not $\pi^{-1}$) appears. To go from the first line to the second, you juste reorder the product for each term ($\pi$ fixed). Since $\pi$ is a permutation, you know there's only one $x$ such that $\pi(x)=1$. And this $x$ is $\pi^{-1}(1)$. So you put the $a_{\pi(x),x}$ first, and you can rewrite it $a_{\pi(x),x}=a_{1,\pi^{-1}}(x)$. Then you look for the only $x'$ such that $\pi(x')=2$, and so on... for the signature, you know that $sgn(\pi^{-1})=sgn(\pi)$

Comment: Now I understand it completely. Cheers my friend!

Answer (score 3):

$\pi \in S_n \Rightarrow \pi^{-1} \in S_n$ and vice versa, so your (finite!) sums are equal.

Comment: You forgot to mention another necessary fact: $\operatorname{sgn}(\pi)=\operatorname{sgn}(\pi^{-1})$ — otherwise the two expressions would not be equal.

Answer (score 0):

Here

$\begin{align*} \det(A)=&\sum_{\sigma\in S_n}\operatorname{sgn}(\sigma)\prod_{i=1}^n a_{i, \sigma(i)}\\
=&\sum_{\sigma\in S_n}\operatorname{sgn}(\sigma^{-1})\prod_{\alpha\in\{(i,\sigma(i))| i\in \{ 1, 2, ..., n\}\}}a_\alpha\\
=&\sum_{\sigma\in S_n}\operatorname{sgn}(\sigma^{-1})\prod_{\alpha\in\{(\sigma^{-1}(i),i| i\in \{ 1, 2, ..., n\}\}}a_\alpha \text{ by the Lemma below}\\
=&\sum_{\sigma\in S_n}\operatorname{sgn}(\sigma^{-1})\prod_{i=1}^n a_{\sigma^{-1}(i),i} \\
=&\sum_{\sigma\in S_n}\operatorname{sgn}(\sigma)\prod_{i=1}^n a_{\sigma(i),i} \\
=& \det(A^T).
\end{align*}$

Lemma: Let $\sigma$ be arbitrary in $S_n$. Then, $\{(i,\sigma(i))| i\in \{ 1, 2, ..., n\}\}=\{(\sigma^{-1}(i), i)| i\in \{ 1, 2, ..., n\}\}$.

Proof: Let $x\in LHS$. Thus, $x=(i, \sigma(i))$ for some $i\in \{1, 2, ..., n\}$. Thus, $\sigma^{-1}(m)=i$ for some $m\in \{1, 2, ..., n\}$. Note $(\sigma^{-1}(m),m)\in RHS$. So, it suffices to show $m=\sigma(i)$. We know $m=\sigma(i)$ as $\sigma(\sigma^{-1}(m))=\sigma(i)\implies m=\sigma(i)$. An analogous argument shows the other way.